# Show $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)m^{-js}$ convergers to $ (1-m^{-s})^{-2}$

Tags: calculus

I would please appreciate help showing: For $m$ a fixed integer

> > $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{j+1}{m^{-js}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{(1-m^{-s})^2}$

There is a hint to treat the sum as a power series in $m^{-s}$.

A power series in $m^{-s}$ itself would converge to $\frac{m^s}{m^s-1}$ (for $m^s>1$).

Even if this is correct, that's as far as I could get, although the $(1-m^{-s})^{-2}$ looks like  a derivative was taken.

Thanks

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Well this is embarrassing. Believe me, I went through all the linked similar questions as I was writing this, hoping to find a comparable. If I had used $n$ rather than $j$ as an index, I would have found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity
$$ |x|<1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{j\geq 0}(j+1)\,x^j $$
follows from [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars). Just set $x=\frac{1}{m^s}$.

Comment: You've lost me at "stars and bars", and that link doesn't enlighten me at all.